# Flex custom validator for TextInput

Tags: apache-flex, numbers, validation, textinput

I'm Flex beginner

I have an InputText for integer input and I want to validate this number that can't not exceed a given max number.

Can anyone recommend me a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NumberValidator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/validators/NumberValidator.html) can help you.

Use `maxValue` property